# How to summarize two different fields in the same row

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a field in the details section that I can sum called @fDispValue

```
IF {@fDispValue2Num} > 0 
THEN {@fDispValue2Num}
ELSE IF {@fAmtOwed2Num} > 0
THEN {@fAmtOwed2Num}
ELSE 0.00
```

As funds are used up, eventually there is insufficient funds left and that leads to a proration percentage @fProrationPercent It is located in Group Footer 1b

```
IF {@fTotalMedsWagesDebtSV}=0 THEN 0 else
IF {@fTotalAssetsAfterJudgmentsSV}/{@fTotalMedsWagesDebtSV}> 1
THEN 1
ELSE {@fTotalAssetsAfterJudgmentsSV}/{@fTotalMedsWagesDebtSV}
```

Next to the @fDispValue in the details section, there is another field with the calculation of the prorated amount @fDispValueProRated

```
IF {@fDispValue2Num} > 0 
THEN {@fDispValue2Num}*{@fProrationPercent}
ELSE IF {@fAmtOwed2Num} > 0
THEN {@fAmtOwed2Num}*{@fProrationPercent}
ELSE 0.00
```

Crystal will not let me Sum the @fDispValueProRated field. Only Field Heading comes up under the rt-clk Insert menu.

I am currently using a workaround by multiplying the Sum of @fDispValue by the @fProrationPercentage but this causes some mismatch due to rounding. @fSumMedsWages

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar TotalMedWagesDebtAmtPdSh;
TotalMedWagesDebtAmtPdSh := IF ISNULL(Sum ({@fDispValue}, {Command.Class}))        then 0.00
ELSE IF {@fTotalAssetsAfterJudgmentsSV} = 0 then 0.00
ELSE
Sum ({@fDispValue}, {Command.Class})*{@fProrationPercent}
```

Why am I able to Sum @fDispValue and not @fDispValueProRated?

Comment: Have you considered using a Running Total for @fDispValueProRated? I know they're a bit more forgiving as opposed to Summary fields.

Comment: I think running total is the best option you can use here... if that is not possible then you need to write a formula to sum one by one for each group and then reset it at start of the group

Comment: @4444 Thanks for the suggestions. I'm not sure how to use running totals since I only want a final sum. If that's possible, I need help!

Comment: You can totally use a Running Total to get a final sum. Just place it in a footer instead of the details section.